# Performance related to ram speed

Tags: performance, cpu, ram

My question is: why overclocking the RAMs does not bring a significant performance increasing?
If I speed up their frequency and/or their latency, I will not get big advantages. 
I can't understand it, considering that the CPU should be able to read and write faster as well as processing data. 
Or maybe the bottleneck is getting smaller because of faster CPUs?
Please give me as much information as you can.

Regards.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a place for programming-related questions. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more info.

Comment: I personally apologize. I didn't know that.

Comment: Performance of what? Programs that spend most of their time doing I/O will not be sped up by overclocking because they are limited by the I/O hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because of two reasons:

1. Keep in mind that not all operations that the CPU does are writing or reading from RAM. While it waits for RAM, it can be computing other things. I don't know what the average RAM-based-operations versus register-based operations ratio.
2. CPU's have ultra fast memory, called L1-, L2-, L3-Cache. These memory units are very very fast, but keep only a few megabytes of data.